# The Error is-Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#

my date format from calendar is 05/02/19 14:29 PM

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=reldate.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
                showsTime: true,
                ifFormat: "%d/%m/%y %H:%M %p",

                align: "BR",
                electric: false,
                singleClick: false,
                displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
                button: ".next()"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I tried many ways to get  a  date from string

I tried parse method and convert method. But I am getting (The Error is-Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.) This error

```
{
  String dateString1 = Request.Form["mardt"];
     //  DateTime marketingdate = Convert.ToDateTime (dateString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);
}
```

I am new to this c# platform.
Please give the solution for this.

Comment: Firstly, do you know what format your date is in? if not, you need to figure it out before asking a question as we don't know either. Please update this question with the results from `dateString1`

Comment: Please give examples of the string.

Comment: my date format  from calendar is 05/02/19 14:29 PM

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the string is not in one of the recognized formats. Some of the sample formats are,

```
string simpleTime = "1/1/2000";
string httpTime = "Fri, 27 Feb 2009 03:11:21 GMT";
string w3Time = "2009/02/26 18:37:58";
string nyTime = "Thursday, February 26, 2009"; 
string perlTime = "February 26, 2009";
string isoTime = "2002-02-10";
string windowsTime = "2/21/2009 10:35 PM";
string windowsPanelTime = "8:04:00 PM";
```

First, make sure the incoming string follows one of the recognized formats. Then, you can use [DateTime.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) to convert the string to a DateTime object.

Here's a snippet:

```
String dateString = Request.Form["mardt"];
//using Parse
DateTime marketingDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
//using ParseExact 
marketingDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,"dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//or use any format you want, refer the msdn links
```

[CustomDateTimeFormatSrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: my date format from calendar is 05/02/19 14:29 PM  


 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=reldate.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
                showsTime: true,
                ifFormat: "%d/%m/%y %H:%M %p",
              
                align: "BR",
                electric: false,
                singleClick: false,
                displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
                button: ".next()"
            });
        });

Comment: @GaneshaMoorthy why not split it as string it then parse it to date or time of your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it will return **05/02/2019** from `05/02/19 14:29 PM`.

`Console.WriteLine(dateString1.GetDate());`

```
public static class Timex
    {
        public static string GetDate(this string JDate)
        {
            if (JDate == null)
            {               
                return "";
            }
            var JDate = JDate.Split(null);                        
            return DateTime.ParseExact(JDate[0], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
}
```